# 60 degree corner molding

Tags: joints

I have a corner joint I need hidden, for which I'd normally use a quarter round molding, but because this is part of a cathedral ceiling, the angle is much narrower than 90 degrees, it's 60 degrees. So, I'd need a "sixth round molding". Is that usually sold in large hardware stores or is this some custom thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took me a couple of minutes to figure out what you were asking, but think I know what your asking.  You need a molding to fit against the ridge beam at the top of a cathedral ceiling? Well my friend, you are not going to find one that is not 90 degrees at a box store. I'm afraid the only good solution is to find a friend with a decent table saw and cut a piece of trim to fit. Use a bevel square and a protractor to measure the angle exactly, then depending on the stock you use, either transfer the angle to the saw for a single triangle trim, or divide it in half and do a double back cut to preserve a front detail of the trim.  Sorry, not enough time or space to do a complete table saw angle cutting primer for ya, but I think you understand the concept.

Comment: Yup, you understood what I meant just right. Sorry for the half-assed wording, most of that vocabulary is beyond what I use daily. "not going to find one that is not 90 degrees at a box store" - just my luck.

Comment: Sorry guy.  you might be able to fudge in some crown molding. there would be less obvious edge gaps.

Comment: All hope is not lost, local Home Depot (or equivalents) have cutting service and most likely table saws. There's also a molding specialist nearby I had never heard of before...

Comment: HD or Lowes will not rip materials.  they will cut to length, but not custom cuts like you need.  Sorry.  But if your in the neighborhood, stop by and I'll cut it for ya!

Comment: Just 6 hours away! I'll check my other places. Thanks again for the advice.

Comment: My son is a computer engineer, so he talks the same language as you!  I just do houses.  Got your passport? LOL

Comment: If there are any non-big-box lumber yards left near you, they will often have a full shop for custom requests like this. I used to source all of the trim for my house from them and they'd cut everything down to match the originals. Alas, my business wasn't enough to keep them going and now it's just Home Depot. :(

Comment: @DA01, @shirlockhomes Home Depot et al. had nothing, but a local community arts centre have a table saw and did it for 5 bucks.